# Proving equality of streams

Tags: list, haskell, infinite, applicative

I have a data type

```
data N a = N a [N a]
```

of rose trees and Applicative instance

```
instance Applicative N where
 pure a = N a (repeat (pure a))
 (N f xs) <*> (N a ys) = N (f a) (zipWith (<*>) xs ys)
```

and need to prove the Applicative laws for it. However, *pure* creates infinitely deep, infinitely branching trees. So, for instance, in proving the homomorphism law

```
pure f <*> pure a = pure (f a)
```

I thought that proving the equality

```
zipWith (<*>) (repeat (pure f)) (repeat (pure a)) = repeat (pure (f a))
```

by the approximation (or take) lemma would work. However, my attempts lead to "vicious circles" in the inductive step. In particular, reducing

```
approx (n + 1) (zipWith (<*>) (repeat (pure f)) (repeat (pure a))
```

gives

```
(pure f <*> pure a) : approx n (repeat (pure (f a)))
```

where *approx* is the approximation function. *How* can I prove the equality without an explicit coinductive proof?

Comment: Why would you want to prove it without using coinduction? Just as induction is the natural proof method for data like finite lists/trees, coinduction is the natural proof method for codata, like streams or your "infinitely deep, infinitely branching trees".

Comment: In particular, because the proof operates at the level of "program syntax." A proof of bisimilarity does not.

Comment: this looks like a good candidate for the cstheory stackexchange site, especially if you stated it in slightly more general/formal terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a sketch of something that I think works and remains at the level of programmatic syntax and equational reasoning.

The basic intuition is that it is much easier to reason about `repeat x` than it is to reason about a stream (and worse yet, a list) in general.

```
uncons (repeat x) = (x, repeat x)

zipWithAp xss yss = 
    let (x,xs) = uncons xss
        (y,ys) = uncons yss
    in (x <*> y) : zipWithAp xs ys

-- provide arguments to zipWithAp
zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y) = 
    let (x',xs) = uncons (repeat x)
        (y',ys) = uncons (repeat y)
    in (x' <*> y') : zipWithAp xs ys

-- substitute definition of uncons...
zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y) = 
    let (x,repeat x) = uncons (repeat x)
        (y,repeat y) = uncons (repeat y)
    in (x <*> y) : zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y)

-- remove now extraneous let clause
zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y) = (x <*> y) : zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y)

-- unfold identity by one step
zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y) = (x <*> y) : (x <*> y) : zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y)

-- (co-)inductive step
zipWithAp (repeat x) (repeat y) = repeat (x <*> y)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the universal property of unfolds (since repeat and a suitably uncurried zipWith are both unfolds). There's a related discussion [on my blog](http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/stream-monad/). But you might also like Ralf Hinze's papers on unique fixpoints [ICFP2008](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/people/ralf.hinze/publications/ICFP08.pdf) (and the subsequent JFP paper).

(Just checking: all your rose trees are infinitely wide and infinitely deep? I'm guessing that the laws won't hold otherwise.)

Answer (score 1):

Why do yo need coinduction?  Just induct.

```
pure f <*> pure a = pure (f a)
```

can also be written (you need to prove the left and right equality)

```
N f [(pure f)] <*> N a [(pure a)] = N (f a) [(pure (f a))]
```

which allows you to off one term at a time.  That gives you your induction.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You actually get `N f (repeat $ pure f) <*> N a (repeat $ pure a) = N (f a) (zipWith (<*>) (repeat $ pure f) (repeat $ pure a))` which leads directly to the equality danportin wants to prove in the first place...